# iBookstore and Kindle

Tags: kindle, books

I bought a book in the iBookstore to read on my iPad, but the iPad isn't that easy on my eyes. I recently bought a Kindle because my grandson said the e-ink would be better for reading. Is there a way to convert the iBook to a format I can read on my Kindle?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to change the file format. 
This might be helpful to you http://calibre-ebook.com/.

Also this is a good resource: http://www.epubor.com/read-ibooks-on-kindle.html.

Good Luck